# ajax response to fail after successful upload

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm using jquery to upload files/images to codeigniter controller.
I have managed to upload the image successfully after a long struggle, however, there is an awkward behavior from the ajax function.

**Problem:** ajax redirects to .fail() while the operation is done successfully

*Here is my code:-*

**Javascript - AJAX call**

```
$.ajax({
            url         : url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false
        }).done(function(response){
            alert(response);
        }).fail(function(request,status,error){
            alert(request.responseText);
        });
```

**Codeigniter PHP-Controller**

```
if( $this->upload->do_upload('item_'.$content_id) ){
    $file_info = $this->upload->data();
    $file_name = $file_info['file_name'];
    $result = $this->contents->update(array('value' => $file_name), $content_id);
    if( $result ){
        echo "success";
        die();
    }
    else{
        echo "fail";
        die();
    }
}
```

The page alerts: *'success'* from the *.fail()* function, as the processed statement is: *alert(request.responseText)*

Any ideas?

Comment: what are the contents of the status and error parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ajax call need response as json but you are sending response as text try to send the response in json format

```
if( $result ){
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'file is uploaded'));
        die();
    }
    else{
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'failed to upload'));
        die();
}
```

Also tweak your ajax code to have success call

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function (data) {
        alert("SUCCESS: " + data.status);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert("ERROR: " + data.status);
    }
})
```

Comment: as for the json response, most of my ajax calls are set to dataType:'json', but i always ecco either 'success' or 'fail' from server for simplicity.

Comment: and as for the success and error, i was once advised to use the new jquery functions (done & fail). in a best practice article. sorry for not being able to provide a link for that.
Anyway, thanks for the help